# Strict REST vs passing a state via a object literal from server side?

Tags: javascript, performance

The company I am working for has a web application where the client side code is part of the monolith backend code. The client is passed it's state via a variable that is templated into the client html. The client is an SPA running Angular.

The argument is that it saves making 4 HTTP requests when the client side starts.

(The below code is not real code, more just an illustration of what I mean)

```
<body>
    <script>
        const state = JSON.parse( {{ generateJSONStateServerMethod() }} )
    </script>
</body>
```

Personally, I'd prefer the client be a separate repo and if it needs to make 4 http requests to set up, so be it. At least you can paint quickly.

However that is just a preference and I am not experienced enough to hold a knowledgeable opinion on the matter.

Which is better, and why?

Answer (score 1):

So, as a rule fewer requests means better performance (in general), if you're measuring performance from the users perspective.  The biggest lag in rendering a page is often all the requests it makes to the server to get all the assets it needs, and a big chunk of this is just the network latency involved.  If you're serving to mobile clients, or clients who aren't on broadband, it's even more noticeable.

That said, depending on how often that configuration information changes, you have other options, including:

1. generating a .js file that can be loaded in a normal script tag
   (rather than embedded as a template item)
2. Combining those four requests into one on the server, and making one
   Ajax call
3. If it changes rarely (or never) make the config file part of your JS
   bundle / build process (you *are* using one, right?) and package it
   with the rest of your Angular code.

There are also advantages to what you're proposing, at its heart (not the part where you need 4 requests, but the part where you're not rendering server-side templates). By making all the HTML static, you can serve it from a CDN or regular (static file) web server, which will definitely reduce server-side lag and (probably) cost.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Paul said is valid, and what you're doing in your code also, it's like the `server rendering` functionality that most modern frameworks support (like React).
So I don't see a big deal in setting the state on server before sending HTML back on the first request.